# How to build mixed array

Tags: go

In ruby I can created array is filled with types:

```
[1, 'hello', :world] # [Fixnum, String, Symbol]
=> [1, "hello", :here]
```

How to implement a similar array is filled with mixed types in Go?

How to declare the array?

Comment: Asking how to write language X in language Y is the wrong approach to different languages. Learn how to solve the problem at hand in idiomatic language Y ways and play to language Y's strengths rather than sticking to whatever language X supported. Why do you want an array different types?? What are you trying to do?? Depending on that there may be many different Go answers (e.g. make an interface that describes the common bit and store a *slice* of those (slices and arrays are different).

Comment: And from reading your comment on an answer I was correct. You don't an array of different types at all, you want a completely different Go construct: multiple returns and/or a struct. My recommendation: Stop. Read the [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec). Take the [Go tour](https://tour.golang.org). Read [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html). Continue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that via the empty interface - `interface{}`:

```
arr := make([]interface{}, 0)

arr = append(arr, "asdfs")
arr = append(arr, 5)
```

or in literal form:

```
arr := []interface{}{"asdfs", 5}
```

Whenever you want to use a value of that array you need to use a type assertion.

Comment: is there just one way (with `Interface`) to implement it?

Comment: @itsnikolay Yeah, Go is statically typed. Why do you need such a mixed list?

Comment: i would like to return array `[year, month, day]` for a result of `time.Now().Date()`

Comment: @itsnikolay Why don't you directly return those results or a struct that contains your values?

Comment: Now I think, that your suggested way is the best in Go world

Comment: yes, use a struct, or just return 3 values.  But, in case you still want a slice, you can create the same slice with a literal:  fmt.Println([]interface{}{"foo",5})